# How to automate an application on Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-application, ubuntu

I am working in Ubuntu. I want to automate a desktop application.

Currently, I have worked with Selenium for automating web application, but Selenium doesn't support desktop applications.

I've heard about AutoIt tool. Does it work on the Ubuntu OS? What should I do?

Comment: Are you testing a Windows application on Ubuntu? You can try out wine.

Comment: How about `sikuli`?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out Sikuli http://www.sikuli.org/.  It works on image recognition so it would work on Windows and non-windows so long as the target image is the same.  I have found that in general it works really well for anything desired.

Answer (score 1):

No, AutoIt does not have an Ubuntu version. It is a windows only automation tool.

The Ubuntu team has their own [test automation pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation), it also lists some tools they use to test their own application.

Other alternatives: https://askubuntu.com/questions/822075/what-is-the-equivalent-tool-for-autoit-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

> I want to automate a desktop application

You need a copy of Windows; installed or a VM.

> I heard about AutoIT. Is it working on ubuntu os ?

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) is only available on Windows and is a scripting tool. It can be paired with Selenium.

> What should I do?

You can use AutoIT + Selenium (A Google search will turn up many guides on how). Otherwise, there are [COTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) that can test desktop applications, like [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/).